# Best Way For Users To Upload Data From Android App To Web Server Database

Tags: android, upload, webserver

I'm writing an app that uses a formula to calculate a number.  The formula however is only an estimate, so I want to get actual results from users so I can improve it.  What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd build a REST API on your web server, and have the Android app feed data back to it so the API can store it in your central database.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE
http://www.slideshare.net/sullis/connecting-to-web-services-on-android/

How you create the API will depend on what platform the API is being built on.